# Open a word document to another computer using CMD, it only stays in Task Manager Processes Tab and doesn't display on the screen of the other PC

Tags: cmd, ms-word, taskmanager

I had created an app that will open a ms word document in another computer (Server) using CMD.

The CMD is called by Java and is executed in server-side.

Upon executing of the command, WINWORD.EXE*32 only stays in Task Manager Processes Tab and also there are no related Task in Application Tab.

Here is the screenshot of the Task Manager (Processes Tab):
[Task Manager Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92DXp.png)

How can I show the Word Application in the other PC?

Comment: Set **Visible property** [see](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationclass.visible.aspx)

Comment: Ivan.s, thanks. but how will I implement Visible Property?

Comment: See link in first post. Publish your code to correct it.

Comment: SOLVED. I included PSEXEC function in the CMD string to open the word document in the other PC (Server).

Comment: Please add any solution updates as an answer below, rather than editing the question. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry halfer but i didn't edit the question itself. I just answer my question and edited the title to add "SOLVED". No worries i'll compose the detailed answer for this if my answer is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. I included PSEXEC in the CMD string that would open the Word Document in the Server-side.

For every time the client-side executes a cmd command-line to the server-side via java, the "User Name" used for WINWORD*32.exe in task manager Processes tab is always "System", [LocalSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx).

Thats why I decided to include PSEXEC to the CMD String in order to log-on to the other admin user in the server-side.

Here is the CMD command line I used in my Runtime.getRuntime().exec:

`CD <PSTools Directory in the server> && psexec \\servername -u username -p password -i 2 cmd /c <Directory of the word doc in the server>`